# Dynamically Created imagebutton is null even after it has been used if app is closed and reopened

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, sharedpreferences, imagebutton

I am programming an app that the user can purchase buildings (drag and drop imagebuttons) that they are allowed to move where they would like on the background. Drag and drop works well and so does the dynamic creation of the imagebuttons works well. I even have sharedpreferences working so that the coordinates of the last spot the building was in is remembered, but the actual imagebutton shows up null when the app is closed and reopened. Thus, it gives me the coordinates, but does not have the button there. My question is, how do I have the app "remember" that the imagebutton has been created so that I can display the button at the coordinates that are saved?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: we can't help unless you write here the part of your code that is doing what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the id of the image that the button had on it, and then when onRestoreInstanceState is called or if you are having it recreate your activity, onCreate() is called, re-initialize the ImageButton with the id. If you loaded it dynamically the first time, you have to load it dynamically when the activity is recreated!

Have the ImageButton as a global variable.

```
private ImageButton myImageButton;

//Code....

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(b);//THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
    b.putInt("image_1", idofyourimage); //This is where you store the id of the image
    //you can store all sorts of data in the bundle, so use whatever works
    //for you.
}



public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle b){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(b);//IMPORTANT
    int imageId = b.getInt("image_1");
    myImageButton = new ImageButton();
    myImageButton.setImageResource(imageId);
    //Any other stuff you need to do
}
```